# VBA auto save as macro with username and time stamp

Tags: vba, logging, save-as

I am trying to have my excel file when someone goes to close it. There will be a save as so I can have a log of the username, date, and time I have most of it worked out I think but I just can't find the last piece to this puzzle I have the following code but fails some how not sure why.

```html
Private Sub ActiveWorkbook_Close()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Year_Run = Year(Date)
If Len(Month(Date)) = 1 Then Month_Run = "0" & Month(Date) Else Month_Run = Month(Date)
If Len(Day(Date)) = 1 Then Day_Run = "0" & Day(Date) Else Day_Run = Day(Date)
Date_Run = " on " & Year_Run & "-" & Month_Run & "-" & Day_Run

If Len(Hour(Time)) = 1 Then Hour_Run = "0" & Hour(Time) Else Hour_Run = Hour(Time)
If Len(Minute(Time)) = 1 Then Min_Run = "0" & Minute(Time) Else Min_Run = Minute(Time)
If Len(Second(Time)) = 1 Then Sec_Run = "0" & Second(Time) Else Sec_Run = Second(Time)
Time_Run = " at " & Hour_Run & "," & Min_Run & "," & Sec_Run

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("\\Path to my folder on our network - " & (Environ$("Username")) & Date_Run & Time_Run & ".xlsm ")
End Sub
```

`

Comment: how does it fail? Error, does something else than expected, crashes? Try `Format(Date,"yyyy-mm-dd")` and `Format(Time,"hh,mm,ss")`. it probably won't solve the problem but is much shorter.

Comment: Decayed Alchemy, your code runs just fine for me. I can think of a number of reasons why it might not be working for you, but the point made by @arcadeprecinct is well taken. It's really difficult to give guidance without knowing exactly what happens on your end when you run the code (even if what happens is nothing). If you describe what you're seeing, I'm pretty confident that either myself or arcadeprecinct will be able to help you the rest of the way.

Comment: I just doesn't safe so I don't know why it won't save. I modified my code for word so I all kinds of research on excel and finding ways to get this to work. So it saves fine where ever you want it too?

Comment: Can you tell me, is your code getting executed when you close your workbook? For example, if you put msgbox "Test" in the beginning of your sub, do you see the messagebox when you close the workbook?

Answer (score 1):

Decayed Alchemy, Do two things:
First, I'm assuming that your code is under Module1, or some place other than item A below. If this is the case start by changing the scope of your subroutine from private to public i.e. `Public Sub ActiveWorkbook_Close()`
then, open the code for ThisWorkbook (item A below). Make sure items B and C are set as they should be. Now call your subroutine as shown in the picture below.

[image]

If the problem you're having is what I think it is, this should do the trick. If it's not, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by item A, B and so on? I have only used VBA code in modules really but I will try to follow what you said and see if I get any form of results.

Comment: Okay that did the job but may I ask why that was so much more work than Word ever was I used about the same code and it worked way to easy. So my main question is why did I have to do the before close?

Comment: Decayed Alchemy, Before we get to your next question, if my first answer solved the problem for you, you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.